# Cronjob in symfony running on docker

Tags: symfony, docker, cron

I am trying to run a symfony command through cron but it is now executing never. The application is runningin docker and I can't find information if I need to specify roles or something else. Other standard linux commands are executed successfully but looks like cron doesn't want to start app/console. Here is my cronjob:

```
*  * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /usr/lib/myApp/app/console myCommand --env=prod >> /usr/lib/myApp/testLog.txt 2>&1
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to run symfony command in docker using cron?

Answer (score 5):

The philosophy of Docker is to have one process per container. That means, you usually have no **init** system and thus, no services running inside the container, e.g. `dbus` or **`cron`**.

There are ways to create your own Docker Image with such an init-system/background service. Images based on Alpine often use *S6*.

Another solution is to have use the cron-service on your host and rewrite the command to something like `docker exec <container_name> /usr/local/bin/php ...`